# How to launch a launch configuration in Eclipse from ANT

Tags: eclipse, ant

Is there a way to launch a run / debug configuration from my ANT script?

Comment: Can't believe this isn't a built-in feature.  If you can assign it a keyboard shortcut why not some kind of alias for ant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the [Ant4Eclipse](http://www.ant4eclipse.org/) plug-in can enable you to run Eclipse launch configurations using ANT.

An [`Exectuor`](http://www.ant4eclipse.org/userguide-coreconcepts) is an ANT task that can run Eclipse launch configurations.